# Dynamically Modifying Incountable Cells on Textbox Change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table that creates new rows through PHP in regard to a database table that gets updated. Each row contains a unique class "rdClass" with an additional number that is incremented by a counter. A textbox is contained within each row with a unique id "workhr" with an additional number that is incremented as well. ***(rdClass0, ..., rdClass[n] ---------- workhr0, ..., workhr[n])***

> ```
> <td class='rdClass" . $counter . "'><input id='workhr" . $counter ."' name='HrsInShift" . $counter . "'></td>
> ```

What I'm trying to do is change the background color of **rdClass#** whenever the value in textbox **workhr#** changes respectively. I've already created a nice script in JQuery but it's not dynamic.

> $(function() {
>
> ```
> content = $('#workhr0').val();
>
> $('#workhr0').keyup(function() { 
>             if ($('#workhr0').val() != content) {
>                 content = $('#workhr0').val();
>                 $('.rdClass0').css("background-color", "blue");
>             }
>             else
>                 $('.rdClass0').css("background-color", "");
>         });
> });
> ```

How could I make this dynamic so that it detects value change for all **workhr[n]** and modify their **rdClass[n]**  background colors respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dynamic_val;
$('[id^=workhr]').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val() != dynamic_val){
        dynamic_val = $(this).val();
        $('.rdClass'+$(this).prop('id').split('workhr')[1]).css('background-color', 'blue');
    }else{
        $('.rdClass'+$(this).prop('id').split('workhr')[1]).css('background-color', 'inherit');
    }
});
```

Comment: Incredible! Thank you very much. It's functioning the way I want it to however when I revert to default textbox value, the color doesn't always go back. Any suggestions?